# ScrollTop function generates Undefined JS error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple code which looks for a date value in a table and scrolls to that position. The below code works but also generates an undefined error which breaks other features.

```
$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('<%=ScrollDate%>')").parent('tr').offset().top -40);
```

`ScrollDate` is system generated and changes every day based on system dates.

The error is

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parent(...).offset() is undefined

I am using `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js` for this.

```html
<table class="ramadan-time table-wrapper-scroll-x my-custom-scrollbar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Day</th>
      <th scope="col">Ramadan</th>
      <th scope="col">April/May</th>
      <th scope="col">Imsak</th>
      <th scope="col">Fajr</th>
      <th scope="col">Sunrise</th>
      <th scope="col">Dhuhr</th>
      <th scope="col">Asr</th>
      <th scope="col">Maghrib</th>
      <th scope="col">Isha</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="Date" data-label="Date">13-04-2021</td>
      <td data-label="Day">Tuesday</td>
      <td data-label="Ramadan">1</td>
      <td data-label="April/May">13</td>
      <td data-label="Imsak">4:29</td>
      <td data-label="Fajr">4:39</td>
      <td data-label="Sunrise">5:55</td>
      <td data-label="Dhuhr">12:22</td>
      <td data-label="Asr">3:50</td>
      <td data-label="Maghrib">6:44</td>
      <td data-label="Isha">8:00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Date" data-label="Date">14-04-2021</td>
      <td data-label="Day">Wednesday</td>
      <td data-label="Ramadan">2</td>
      <td data-label="April/May">14</td>
      <td data-label="Imsak">4:28</td>
      <td data-label="Fajr">4:38</td>
      <td data-label="Sunrise">5:54</td>
      <td data-label="Dhuhr">12:22</td>
      <td data-label="Asr">3:49</td>
      <td data-label="Maghrib">6:44</td>
      <td data-label="Isha">8:01</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td class="Date" data-label="Date">15-04-2021</td>
      <td data-label="Day">Thursday</td>
      <td data-label="Ramadan">3</td>
      <td data-label="April/May">15</td>
      <td data-label="Imsak">4:27</td>
      <td data-label="Fajr">4:37</td>
      <td data-label="Sunrise">5:53</td>
      <td data-label="Dhuhr">12:22</td>
      <td data-label="Asr">3:49</td>
      <td data-label="Maghrib">6:45</td>
      <td data-label="Isha">8:01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`<td class="Date" data-label="Date">13-04-2021</td>` is a hidden column only used for scroll calculation. This could be the reason as pointed out in one of the solutions by Juan.

Comment: `$("*:contains('<%=ScrollDate%>')").parent('tr')` is returning undefined, so there is no object to call the `offset()` function on. Without seeing the structure of the HTML, I'm afraid we can't help you understand why that is.

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to find the offset, of an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe save your target element as a variable, and then define your function after that variable is set.

Comment: @Tim i have added table data with 3 rows as table is very long for reference..

Comment: entertain me here : `<%= =>` comes from ASP.net right? if this is a pure js file, is that being outputtet into the source? or is this an `.aspx` file?

Comment: @Stender Yes its asp.net Variable and will be replace by `25-04-2021` in output

Comment: @Learning and does it work if you replace the `<%= =>` part with the hardcoded value of `25-04-2021` - and can you *confirm* that it *does* replace with that value (that that it "will be")

Comment: Just check it's found first, ie `var cell = $("*:contains('<%=ScrollDate%>')").parent("tr"); if (cell.length > 0) $(window).scrollTop(cell.offset().top - 40);`

Comment: Could it be that there's *another* entry in your html that has text content of the value you're searching?  Maybe make your selector more specific, eg `$("table.ramadan-time > tbody > tr > td:contains(...`.    If that's not possible, or still doesn't work, as you've tagged this [javascript]/[jquery] please provide a *complete* [mcve] that demonstrates the issue - ie just html+js/jquery.  No asp.net codes - a complete, self-contained snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no data that matches, the jquery returns a collection with `.length === 0` - attempting `.offset()` on this gives undefined, and `undefined.top` will give an error.

Check if there is a matching date *before* calling offset() on it.

Note also that `*:contains()` will return all of the parent nodes as well.  You should use a more specific selector.

In your example, use:

```
$("table.ramadan-time > tbody td.Date:contains('<%=ScrollDate%>')")
```

adding that with a check gives:

```
var cell = $("table.ramadan-time > tbody td.Date:contains('<%=ScrollDate%>')");
if (cell.length > 0) {
    $(window).scrollTop(cell.parent('tr').offset().top - 40);
}
```

```js
$("#b1").click(() => {
  var cell = $("table.ramadan-time > tbody td.Date:contains('31-12-2099')");
  if (cell.length > 0) {
    $(window).scrollTop(cell.parent('tr').offset().top - 40);
  }
});

$("#b2").click(() => {
  var cell = $("table.ramadan-time > tbody td.Date:contains('31-12-2099')");
  $(window).scrollTop(cell.parent('tr').offset().top - 40);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ramadan-time table-wrapper-scroll-x my-custom-scrollbar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Day</th>
      <th scope="col">Ramadan</th>
      <th scope="col">April/May</th>
      <th scope="col">Imsak</th>
      <th scope="col">Fajr</th>
      <th scope="col">Sunrise</th>
      <th scope="col">Dhuhr</th>
      <th scope="col">Asr</th>
      <th scope="col">Maghrib</th>
      <th scope="col">Isha</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="Date" data-label="Date">13-04-2021</td>
      <td data-label="Day">Tuesday</td>
      <td data-label="Ramadan">1</td>
      <td data-label="April/May">13</td>
      <td data-label="Imsak">4:29</td>
      <td data-label="Fajr">4:39</td>
      <td data-label="Sunrise">5:55</td>
      <td data-label="Dhuhr">12:22</td>
      <td data-label="Asr">3:50</td>
      <td data-label="Maghrib">6:44</td>
      <td data-label="Isha">8:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Date" data-label="Date">14-04-2021</td>
      <td data-label="Day">Wednesday</td>
      <td data-label="Ramadan">2</td>
      <td data-label="April/May">14</td>
      <td data-label="Imsak">4:28</td>
      <td data-label="Fajr">4:38</td>
      <td data-label="Sunrise">5:54</td>
      <td data-label="Dhuhr">12:22</td>
      <td data-label="Asr">3:49</td>
      <td data-label="Maghrib">6:44</td>
      <td data-label="Isha">8:01</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Date" data-label="Date">15-04-2021</td>
      <td data-label="Day">Thursday</td>
      <td data-label="Ramadan">3</td>
      <td data-label="April/May">15</td>
      <td data-label="Imsak">4:27</td>
      <td data-label="Fajr">4:37</td>
      <td data-label="Sunrise">5:53</td>
      <td data-label="Dhuhr">12:22</td>
      <td data-label="Asr">3:49</td>
      <td data-label="Maghrib">6:45</td>
      <td data-label="Isha">8:01</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<hr/>

<button type="button" id="b1">no error when not found</button>
<button type="button" id="b2">original, error when not found</button>
```